# why my apache rewriterule does not work?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

If I write `.htaccess` file like this :

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ test.php
```

It make `127.0.0.1/everyword` ---->`127.0.0.1/test.php`

But if I change `.htaccess` file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^database/(w+)_(d+)/?$ database.php?$1=$2
```

It can not make `127.0.0.1/database/league_1`---->`127.0.0.1/database.php?league=1`

The server said:

> The requested URL /database/league_1 was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex:

```
^database/(w+)_(d+)/?$
```

matches "database", then a "/", then one or more "w"'s (literally the letter "w"), a "_", then one or more "d"'s (literally the letter "d"). You want to escape the "w" and "d":

```
^database/(\w+)_(\d+)/?$
```